# Terminator - keyboard shortcut to open multiple tabs

Tags: terminator, keyboard-accelerators

I want to bind a custom hotkey to opening terminator with two tabs, each tab executing different command

banging my head for hours here :)

Comment: 1. bash alias didn't work. once I start a process from a terminal tab, the other tab will open only after the first finishes

2. bind a hotkey to a bash script with the command /path/to/script.sh 

3. added bash: bash /path/to/script.sh as well

I'm also kinda new to bash scripting so I don't know how to write the bash script for that

Answer (score 0):

Define a couple of profiles and a layout for `terminator`:

```
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    # Your default profile remains untouched...
 [[command1]]
    use_custom_command = True
    custom_command = "watch date"
 [[command2]]
    use_custom_command = True
    custom_command = "top"
[layouts]
  [[default]]
  # Your default layout remains untouched...
  [[your-layout]]
    [[[child0]]]
      type = Window
      order = 0
      parent = ""
    [[[child1]]]
      labels = None, None
      type = Notebook
      order = 0
      parent = child0
    [[[terminal3]]]
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      profile = command1
    [[[terminal2]]]
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = child1
      profile = command2
```

Now if you launch `terminator` thus:

```
terminator --layout your-layout
```

It should open a Terminator window with two tabs running the two commands. Now set the above command to a shortcut key or an alias.

Comment: worked:
this executes both commands on separate tabs.

didn't work:
1. When I hit ctrl+c, the window exits or freezes, tho it's no longer function.
2. It doesn't load zsh, even tho it's my default and I've set login_shell = True. Thoughts about this?